# Use of static member in Android Application bad?

Tags: android, design-patterns

I've stumpled upon an Android Application Class which implements the Singleton pattern and bind a static object to it.

```
public class App extends Application 
{
    public static BigObject myObj;

    private static App instance;

    public static App getInstance()
    {
         return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         instance = this;
         myObj = new BigObject(this);
    }

}
```

Are there any problems with this implementation, regarding performance, memory leaks or maybe Exceptions, when getInstance().myObj.something() is called form BroadcastReceiver or Service?

Comment: I'm interested in seeing a good answer to this one too. Android Studio warns me about `static` variables in `Application` class as well, about memory leaks.

Comment: Yes me too and on the other hand there are a lot of those implementations here on stackoverflow and various blogs.

Comment: Why use static and getInstance? You can access application object everywhere you has context object. So you make bigObject simple field and access it via getter.

Comment: In our project we have classes where we need logging (own lib with logging to our backend) and there wie do not have a context. But nevertheless I've seen a lot of those implementations all over StackOverflow and various blog and I am wondering about the same thing you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only drawback I see is somewhat ugly code, using dependency injection would be better. I don't know, but if OS guarantees that all other components will be launched after Application::onCreate than there is no issues. Even non-main threads will not cache value of bigObject. But if you want set value of bigObject after onCreate, or it's creation takes long time you can face issues with data racing or slow startup.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems with this implementation. The Application object is basically a singleton.

Comment: Yes but Android Studio warns me about having static objects in Application class and it feels bad feels bad for me to have a singleton implemented in an Application class which is basically a singleton.